# Configure GCC to add compile flags globally

Tags: gcc, compilation

Can I configure GCC to add some file globally, for every project? I want to make it temporarily and only with flags like: `-fdiagnostics-color`.

Comment: What do you mean by add, to add file to compilation line ?
What for?

Comment: Are you sure you need that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you need it but you can do a wrapper:

1. `which gcc` - will print a patch to GCC (copy it to clipboard)
2. `mkdir somedir; cd somedir`
3. create file with name `gcc`
   and add into it:           `full path to gcc(from clipboard)   -fdiagnostics-color somefile.c $@`    this command will add `-fdiagnostics-color somefile.c` before every line that came to gcc.
4. `chmod +x gcc` - set execution rights to gcc wrapper
5. And finally
   add path to your wrapper.   `export PATH=somedir:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You might read about [GCC spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) and alter the spec file used by your particular version of `gcc`. But this is generally frowned upon.

The usual practice would be to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and add a `CFLAGS += -fdiagnostics-color` to your `Makefile`. BTW with a recent enough GCC this (adding `-fdiagnostics-color` flag) is not even necessary [since](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html) (at least by setting your `GCC_COLORS` environment variable) the default is `-fdiagnostics-color=auto`

Comment: This flag is necessary if you build from an editor or an IDE, which intercept stdout of the compiler. If GCC detects piping, it turns the diagnostic colors off.