# Is it possible to pass GCC arguments directly from C source code?

Tags: c, gcc, arguments, c-preprocessor

I want to be able to pass arguments to `GCC` from my `C` source code, something like this...

```
// pass the "-ggdb" argument to GCC (I know this won't work!)
#define GCC_DEBUG_ARG -ggdb
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

With this code I'd like to simply run `gcc myfile.c` which would really run `gcc myfile.c -ggdb` (as the "-ggdb" argument has been picked up from the C source code).

I'm not interested in using `make` with the `CFLAGS` environment variable, **I just want to know if its possible to embed `GCC` options within C source code**

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: The conventional way to solve this would be to ship a `Makefile` alongside with the source proper showing how exactly to compile your source code.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain more why you don't want to use `make` (or to pass compiler options to `gcc`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just wanted to see if it was possible, out of curiousity

Comment: Well, to me, it sounds like you do want to use make because this is one of reasons why make is even a thing. Writing a line only twice per project lifetime (`gcc myfile.c` type of projects don't really need anything else, probably), modifying it slightly when needed, and then using `make debug` and `make release` sounds exactly like what you want. Don't XY problem us, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What you want to do is not possible in general.

However, recent GCC (e.g. [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in end of 2018) accepts [many options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and *some* of them could be passed by [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) or by [function specific pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) (However, they don't accept `-g` but do accept `-O2`).

Also, you can use `-g` in every compilation (with GCC, it is mixable with optimization flags such as `-O2`; so runtime performance won't suffer. Of course the `-g` will increase compile time and size of produced object file). Notice that (on Linux) the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information is visible in the generated assembler file (e.g. try to compile your `foo.c` with `gcc -Wall -g -O -S -fverbose-asm foo.c`, look into the generated `foo.s`, and repeat by removing the `-g`)

> I'd like to simply run `gcc myfile.c`

That is a **very bad habit**. You should run `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g myfile.c -o myprog` to get all warnings (you *really* want them) and debug info in your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) `myprog`. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before continuing coding your program.

> I'm not interested in using make with the CFLAGS environment variable

But **you really should**. ***[Using `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)*** or some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html), [rake](https://ruby.github.io/rake/), etc, etc....) ***is***, in practice, ***the conventional and usual way of using GCC***.

Alternatively, on Linux, write a tiny [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) doing the compilation (this is particularly worthwhile if your program is a single source file; for anything bigger, you *really* should use some build automation tool). At last, if you use [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) as your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), you could add a few lines of comments (like at [end of my `manydl.c`](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c#L527) example) specifying [Emacs file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) to tune the [compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) (done from `emacs`)

If these conventions surprise you, read about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) then study -for inspiration- the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), or in your favorite Linux distribution).

At last, **[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) itself is a free software project** (but a huge one of more than five millions lines of mostly C++ source code). So **you can improve it** the way you desire (if you follow its [GPLv3+](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html) license), after having studying somehow its source code. That would take you several months (or years) of work (because GCC is very complex to understand).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292535/841108) to a related question.

You might also (but I recommend not to, because it is very confusing) play tricks with your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and have some directory there -e.g. `$HOME/bin/`, ahead of `/usr/bin/` which contains `/usr/bin/gcc`, with your shell script named `gcc`; but don't do that, you'll be confused. Instead write some "generic" `mygcc` [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) which would run `/usr/bin/gcc` and add appropriate flags to it (I believe it is not worth the effort).